# How to verify locally that a Coverity C++ issue has been fixed

Tags: visual-studio, coverity

How to verify locally that a Coverity C++ issue has been fixed. Particularly, which menu do you select from Coverity menu(the Coverity menu that comes into existence in VS only after the plugin has been installed in VS) ?

Comment: "How to verify locally that a Coverity C++ issue has been fixed." would make a good search term. This is probably a little too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with Coverity on Windows. The UNIX way of doing things is to run the following

1. `cov-build`
2. `cov-analyze`
3. `cov-format-errors`

This does everything locally without submitting to the server database (which is done with `cov-commit-defects`).

With a bit of googling, it looks like the VS menus have options for build and analysis and in the "Coverity Issues" panel there is a choice between Local and Remote.